# How to convert yyyymmddhh24miss to seconds linux

Tags: linux

How to convert yyyymmddhhmiss to seconds (ie 20160510101135 to seconds).

Actually I need to find the difference between input date with current date.

```
dt=20160510101135

echo "Diff: $(date -d @$(($(date +%s)-$dt)) +"%M minutes %S seconds")"
```

I need to convert dt to seconds.

Comment: By "linux" do you actually mean "in bash"? (Anything stopping you from using, say, Python if that ended up making the code simpler?)

Comment: And the other part of my question? Would you be happy to launch Python with a command that parsed the value, worked out the difference and printed it out?

Comment: Presumably that's seconds since 1-1-1970, per Linux convention?